# Same Keras script works in WSL (Ubuntu) but not in Conda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a CNN to classify images and I have a Keras script that successfully runs in both a CPU and GPU environment, but the network only learns in the CPU environment. In the GPU environment, loss decreases after the first epoch, but stays constant after that. Why?

Using Python 3.6, I have a tensorflow environment running in WSL (Ubuntu) and a tensorflow-gpu environment running in Conda. I've tried different architectures and different optimizers, but no matter what I have issues with the GPU environment.

**Edit:** I created a CPU conda environment and I have the same problem, so it appears to be an issue of Conda vs WSL instead of GPU vs CPU. Also, Conda's epochs on CPU are twice as fast as the CPU epochs in WSL.

I commented out model.fit() for less verbose output.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

import utils

(x_train, y_train), _, (x_test, y_test) = utils.load_data(limit=36)

input_image = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))    
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_image)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=input_image, outputs=output)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['acc'])

# model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
for i in range(25):
    print(str(i) + ': ' + str(model.train_on_batch(x_train, y_train)))
model.evaluate(x_train, y_train)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Result of CPU training:

```
0: [17.486359, 0.6875]
1: [61761.203, 0.28125]
2: [2228.4707, 0.71875]
3: [4440.558, 0.28125]
4: [1062.5581, 0.71875]
5: [481.29315, 0.71875]
6: [234.01581, 0.4375]
7: [170.98215, 0.71875]
8: [38.968575, 0.6875]
9: [8.086919, 0.75]
10: [5.7502546, 0.375]
11: [72.89319, 0.71875]
12: [13.203195, 0.6875]
13: [1.4184309, 0.875]
14: [9.258236, 0.46875]
15: [23.165062, 0.71875]
16: [8.963888, 0.78125]
17: [3.1053305, 0.84375]
18: [1.0664859, 0.96875]
19: [0.039992813, 1.0]
20: [0.023323938, 1.0]
21: [0.019487603, 1.0]
22: [0.01734325, 1.0]
23: [0.015670585, 1.0]
24: [0.014209943, 1.0]
32/32 [==============================] - 1s 19ms/sample - loss: 0.0129 - acc: 1.0000
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/sample - loss: 2.3463 - acc: 0.7500
```

I would expect to see something similar to the above, but I get this weird stuff instead--result of GPU training:

```
0: [8.630159, 0.1875]
1: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
2: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
3: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
4: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
5: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
6: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
7: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
8: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
9: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
10: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
11: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
12: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
13: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
14: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
15: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
16: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
17: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
18: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
19: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
20: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
21: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
22: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
23: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
24: [4.5332146, 0.71875]
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/sample - loss: 4.5332 - acc: 0.7188
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/sample - loss: 4.0295 - acc: 0.7500
```

I can't wait to see what stupid mistake I'm making lol

Comment: I wish I could replicate this. do you have absolutely same code and data? same 32 datapoints? with the same split? (what is the dataset?)

Comment: @Mehdi Absolutely same code and data. One thing I just realized though is that when using a CPU conda environment I get the same issue. So it seems like a problem of Conda vs WSL instead of CPU vs GPU.

Comment: @Mehdi it's the training set from the ISIC challenge. One more thing I just noticed is that training is about twice as fast in Conda as it is in WSL...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the actual problem was, but I do know updating tensorflow-gpu from 1.13.1 fixed it.

In the conda shell, I ran `pip install tf-nightly-gpu`, and now the network trains as expected. I bet that I didn't have to use the nightly build and I could have just specified 1.14.0 (the tensorflow-gpu build I'm using in WSL) but whatever.